# Can't mount Time Capsule via Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, mount, time-machine, airport, time-capsule

I have an Apple Time Capsule, and have been able to back up to it without a problem for the past few months. However, today I found I cannot connect to the Time Capsule from Finder, though it appears there, when I click "connect as...", it takes a few seconds and then reports connect failed, "the server may not exist or it is not operational at this time. Check the server name or IP address and your network connection and try again".

When I check Time Machine, it says the last backup failed because "the backup volume could not be mounted".

The strange part is, the Time Capsule is also my router, and I am able to use the Time Capsule as a wireless access point without a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you rebooted both the time capsule and the computer?

Comment: Yes. Also updated the time capsule's firmware, no luck.

Comment: I have this same issue except I can also back up to the capsule via Time Machine - I just can't mount the volume in Finder

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the hard drive crapped out. The router will still work even if the drive is having problems, two separate systems. Pretty much works like an Airport Extreme. If you are under warranty I would suggest taking it to the Apple Store. If you are not, open it up and take the Hard Drive out. Use a SATA to USB adapter to connect it to your Mac and see if you can mount it. If it won't mount there are file recovery and drive scanning software that you can try. If you can't get it working then you will probably have to replace the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar problems - however I can get to the drive with Finder - so I suspect my problem is corruption, although possibly the drive is on its way out.
I'm going to try either Disk Utility or DiskWarrior, first.

Note that if you have any current Applecare on your main machines, the Time Capsule is also covered (even if not purchased at the same time), it counts as a peripheral like a mouse.

There are lots of instructions online about how to get the Time Capsule disassembled - you need to take the rubber boot off with a hairdryer/ hot air gun first.

Comment: Hard drive is bust - getting lots of error messages about hardware failure from Diskwarrior.
Back to the Apple store and they've offered to replace it.
They are doing some out of warranty repairs as they acknowledge a design defect in the 1st gen, worth trying your luck if you have a nearby Apple store.